# Problem with user uid using authentication with Firebase in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Below is my google Sign In page for the app I am trying to build in Flutter. The authenitification process works but when updateScore() and getUserScore() are getting called, both don't work because no user uid is returned. In fact, after debugging, if found out uid returned a null. I don't understand why the uid is not returning even though the user is already logged in and other documents and collections in Firebase like name and email are able to be changed when the user signs in.Is there any other or better way to make use of the google sign in for the user uid to be stored correctly in momery with the authentifaction package from firebase. Thank you!

````
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  User? _user;

  User get user => _user!;

  Future<void> googleLogin() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) return;

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      final userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      _user = userCredential.user;
      if (_user == null) return;

      print("User UID: ${_user!.uid}");

      // Now save user-specific data to Firestore
      await createUserDocument(_user!.uid, {
        "name": _user!.displayName,
        "email": _user!.email,
        "profilePicture": _user!.photoURL,
        "GINO": "Moi et tout ceux qui le veulent",
        "Lasagne": "chaude",
        // Add other user-specific data fields as needed
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> createUserDocument(String userId, Map<String, dynamic> userData) async {
    final userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
    final userDocument = userCollection.doc(userId);

    // Create the main user document
    await userDocument.set(userData);



      // Set the initial score to 0 for new users
    await userDocument.update({"score": 0});


    print("User document and subcollections created successfully.");
  }
  // SCORE STUFF

Future<void> updateScore(int newScore) async {
  final userId = _user?.uid;
  if (userId == null) {
    // Handle the case when the user is not signed in
    return print("I am tired of this shit");
  }

  final userDocument = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId);

   print("User UID before score update: $userId");
  
  // Update the user's score in Firestore
  await userDocument.update({"score": newScore});
  print("Score was added YES");

}


Future<int?> getUserScore() async {
  final userId = _user?.uid;
  if (userId == null) {
    // Handle the case when the user is not signed in
    return null;
  }

  final userDocument = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId);

  print("User UID before score retrieval: $userId");
  
  try {
    // Retrieve the user's score from Firestore
    final userData = await userDocument.get();
    final score = userData.data()?["score"] as int?;
    return score;
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during data retrieval
    print("Error retrieving user score: $e");
    return null;
  }
}

Future<void> updateScoretest(int newScore) async {
  final userId = _user?.uid;
  print("WTF $userId");

  final userDocument = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId);
  // Update the user's score in Firestore
  userDocument.update({"score": newScore});
  print("Score was added YESSIR");

}

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut(); // Disconnect from Google
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(); // Sign out from Firebase

    _user = null; // Reset the user object
    notifyListeners(); // Notify listeners about the change in authentication state
  }

  void updateFlashcardSwipeData({required String building, required flashcardId, required bool isCorrect}) {}
}
```

I tried to debug and obtained that the value for user uid in updateScore() and getusersScore() are both null which means I am not able to make changes to my database.
````

Comment: Have you write rules for allow only authenticated users write data to database?

Comment: If you allow only authenticated users write data to database and `createUserDocument` failed, Most likely user didn't login successfully.

Comment: Yes the rules have been modified to allow for every documents to be modified @flutroid . Do you know which functions I could use to make sure the user successfully log in and therefore save its uid? Thank you, it is really appreciated.